# Filter nested populated array

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-populate

Lets say I have a classroom that look like this:

```
{
    courseName: String,
    teacher: ObjectId,
    students: [{type: ObjectId, ref: 'Student'}]
}
```

and the "Student" schema looks like this:

```
{
    personalInfo: PersonalInfo,
    proffesionalInfo: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'ProffesionalInfo'}
}
```

and the "ProffesionalInfo" schema looks like this:

```
{
    allgrades: [Number],
    averageGrade: Number,
    ...
    ...
}
```

I have the classroom _id and I want to get only the students that their average is lower than 90.
The way I am doing it now is like this:

```
Classroom.findOne({ _id })
        .populate("teacher", "_id name")
        .populate({
            path: 'ridesstudents',
            select: 'proffesionalInfo',
            populate: [
                {
                    path: "proffesionalInfo",
                    select: "allgrades averageGrade"
                }
            ]
        })
        .then(classroom => {
            classroom.students = classroom.students.filter(student => student.proffesionalInfo.averageGrade < 90);
            resolve(user);
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
```

As you can see I am filtering after bringing all student.
In case I have 10 million student and only 2 with grade less than 90 It is "not good" approach.

How can I filter the students within the query and not bringing all of them and then filtering??

*side note - the data above is only an exaple which target is to bring the general idea. dont get into details.*

Answer (score 0):

Try using aggregate:

```
let classroom = Classroom.aggregate([
   { $match: { _id: classroomId } },
   { $lookup: {
        from: "students",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "students",
        pipeline:[
          { $lookup: {
               from: "professionalInfo",
               localField: "_id",
               foreignField: "proffesionalInfo",
               as:"professionalInfo"
          }},
          { $match: {$lte: ["professionalInfo.averageGrade",90]}}
        ]
        as: "students"
 }}])
```